# If-else working unexpectedly in android studio. why?

Tags: android

I am trying to make an app which takes URL and tells whether this URL is valid or not. (There is no any great intention for making this app but just to learn android development).

I used if-else in button. it must output "if" section but it gives out "else" section.

**CODE**

```
TextView tv;
EditText urlScan;
Button btn;
private static final String EXAMPLE_DOT_COM = "[a-z]+[\\.]{1}[a-z]{2,3}";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv = findViewById(R.id.tv);
    urlScan = findViewById(R.id.webInput);
    btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);


    String webUrl = urlScan.getText().toString();

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (webUrl.equals(EXAMPLE_DOT_COM)){
                tv.setText("Valid URL");
            }
            else {
                tv.setText("Invalid");

            }
        }
    });

}
```

**INPUT**
google.com

**Expected output**
Valid URL

**OUTPUT**
Invalid

Comment: you should use regex instead of equal() method as it will compare that both string are equal or not which will mostly fails until and unless your webUrl is `EXAMPLE_DOT_COM` to it.

Comment: Don't need to use regex , there is a better option available , use `URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)` to check if it's a valid url or not

Comment: @Nitish, You're right. Yet, obviously, the OP misunderstood regex patterns. That's why the answer should be related to that. Still, I suggest that you add that as an answer since it's your idea.

Comment: @SalihKavaf , yes , since error of already explained in the comment and the  answer , I thought of giving the alternative solution . Have added the answer for the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing a regex pattern to the URL you want to check, which isn't correct.
Use regex matching instead:

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher; // Don't forget to add the required imports
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

TextView tv;
EditText urlScan;
Button btn;
private static final String EXAMPLE_DOT_COM = "[a-z]+[\\.]{1}[a-z]{2,3}";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv = findViewById(R.id.tv);
    urlScan = findViewById(R.id.webInput);
    btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);


    String webUrl = urlScan.getText().toString();

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            
            // Create a new pattern...
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EXAMPLE_DOT_COM, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

            // Match the URL string...
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(webUrl);
            boolean matchFound = matcher.find();
            
            // Check whether it matches...
            if (matchFound){
                tv.setText("Valid URL");
            }
            else {
                tv.setText("Invalid");

            }
        }
    });

}
```

Your can learn more about Java Regex [here](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_regex.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Don't need to use regex , there is a better option available , use `URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)` to check if it's a valid url or not

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv = findViewById(R.id.tv);
    urlScan = findViewById(R.id.webInput);
    btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);


    String webUrl = urlScan.getText().toString();

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)){
                tv.setText("Valid URL");
            }
            else {
                tv.setText("Invalid");    
            }
        }
    });

}
```